# Regular expression validator on mouse up

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

How can I set the regular expression validator on mouse up not on a button click for the validation group? What I mean is that I need to get the error message on mouse up and not when I click on the submit button

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ControlToValidate="timetosend" ValidationExpression="(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})$" EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="The format of the time must be xx:xx !" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contentGRP" /></td>
```

Note that I'm using asp.net with vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the java script event `MouseOver` that will fire when mouse is moved over that particular entity..

For example..if you want mouse over event on text box..

```
<input type="button" onmouseover="javascript:document.getElementById('textbox').value='Hello'" />
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" />
```

For example:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Similarly..you can get  the data from you html element and then match it regular expression and validate it accordingly

Comment: It's generally considered good to give an example of how you think this should be done.

Comment: @Avinash okey but how can i call the validator on the mouse over?

Comment: I guess the ASP.net validators works only on button click event if you want to do it based on other events..you have to go for  java script events as i mentioned above..

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateOnMouseOver(){$('#timetosend').mouseover(
function(){
    ValidatorValidate($('#RegularExpressionValidator2').get(0),"contentGRP",null);
   });}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(ValidateOnMouseOver);
```

The second parameter of function ValidatorValidate($('#RegularExpressionValidator2').get(0),"contentGRP",null); is validation group name